# ActivityNotFoundException wnen using Camcorder.(android.media.action.VIDEO_CAMERA )

Tags: android, video-recording

I want to implement VideoRecording function. I have the below code,but it throws me this error. How can I rectify it.

**Here is my code,**

```
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA);
        cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 30);
           startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,TAKE_PICTURE_WITH_CAMERA);
```

**Logcat Details**

```
07-28 11:59:22.271: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5590): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.media.action.VIDEO_CAMERA (has extras) }
07-28 11:59:22.271: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5590):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
07-28 11:59:22.271: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5590):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
07-28 11:59:22.271: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5590):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which API level you are using? bcoz android.intent.extra.durationLimit will work from API level 8 on-wards.

From the Android ref doc:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

public static final String EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT

**Since: API Level 8**
Specify the maximum allowed recording duration in seconds.
Constant Value: "android.intent.extra.durationLimit"

I suspect that could be the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using  `Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAMERA");` for VideoRecording.

Comment: If I use this still I am not able to limit my duration. have you got any idea on that